# Send email that will not receive out of office replies?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, out-of-office

As part of my job, I often send internal messages to large distribution groups.  I do not require the flood of out of office messages that comes back, but still need to allow actual humans to reply to me.

With Outlook 2010, is there any way to turn off receiving out of office messages back on a per-email basis?

There was a simple checkbox for this in Lotus Notes mail which I miss badly.

Comment: Since these automatic replies are generated outside your system, they have to come into your mail client unless you have your own mail server where rules could be defined to handle them first. Like both of the answers implied, it's usually not a good idea to have things automatically disappear completely because something useful might get deleted and you would never know.

Comment: @Joe These are all internal emails, through our enterprise Exchange implementation of that opens up new options.   Using rules is too persnickety to bother with, as for small email targeted to individuals or small groups, I might want o see out of office notices so a global "delete automated reply" rule is not appropriate; and yet, when a blast goes to 2000 people, I surely do not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An Auto-Reply filter is probably the best way to go about doing this:

Create a new rule with the following conditions:

select Conditions: "`which is an automatic reply`"

select Actions: "`Move it to the specified folder`" or "delete it"

I would recommend you use the "Move it to the specified folder" option instead of delete though.  This rule will be active all the time and you don't necessarily want all your regular out of office messages (at other time periods) to get auto-deleted.  By filtering to a folder, you can then picka nd choose what you do with the messages from then on.

Comment: This is the least-bad option, so I am accepting it.   But it looks like there is no such feature in Outlook, at least one that can be enabled on a message by message basis, and that is a real gap.

Answer (score 5):

I would either:

- Use a filter as described in other answers *but* with an additional a rule on the words contained in the "subject" line: those I use in my announcement. (E.g. "subject contains 'internal announcement'")
- Or, use a "do-not-reply" address when sending the e-mail and add a link "if you need to answer this e-mail, please `<A HREF="mailto:me@work.com">click here</A>`"

Answer (score 4):

You can filter those emails to detect the out of office reply and send them to out of office folder which you can hit delete to easily.

**EDIT**

Open Outlook's Rules Wizard and create a rule using Apply this rule after the message arrives.

On the Conditions page, choose "which is an automatic reply" and select Delete the message as the action.

Comment: Filtering is tricky to get right, and breaks easily if for example someone changes the default subject line in their out of office configuration.  That isn't really a solution in my opinion.

Comment: Open Outlook's Rules Wizard and create a rule using Apply this rule after the message arrives.

On the Conditions page, choose "which is an automatic reply" and select Delete the message as the action. this is the only way to do it in outlook 2010 other than filtering it

Comment: Andrew, your comment was actually before the other answers (both answers are the same as your comment), you should [edit your answer](http://superuser.com/posts/767937/edit) move your last comment to the post as it will make it s a good answer.

Comment: thank you dave for telling me how to move it i didn't know i could now, but i am happy as long as the user can fix their problem

Answer (score 2):

Very late reply, but there is a MIME header that is supposed to control this, `X-Auto-Response-Suppress:`, so if your workplace's version(s) of Exchange/Outlook obeys it, then all you have to do is figure out how to add your header to the message.

Here's what looks like a working option for adding arbitrary headers to your emails:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803977/how-do-i-specify-x-headers-for-outgoing-emails-in-microsoft-outlook-2010